# Halacha LeMoshe MiSinais which are taught together were originally said together

Tags: sources-mekorot, halacha-lemoshe-misinai

I seem to remember seeing somewhere, maybe **Tosafos** somewhere, saying that when the *gemarra* groups certain *halacha lemoshe misinai*'s together, like [**Sukkah** 5b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sukkah.5b.13?lang=bi) with `שיעורין חציצין ומחיצין`, it's telling you that these laws were taught together at Sinai. This is why they're grouped together in this fashion in the *gemarra* (since sometimes we find *halacha lemoshe misinai*'s on their own, or in a listing).

Where is this idea stated? I'd appreciate a source.

Comment: What's not clear? Please comment if you think this needs improvement.

Comment: The biggest problem I have with the way your question is worded is that there is no such Gemara of גוד לבוד ודופן עקומה הלכה למשה מסיני. But if I’m understanding the spirit of your question correctly, Sukkah 5b/Eruvin 4b, Sukkah 34a/44a/MK 3b/Taanis 3a/Zevachim 110b, Niddah 72b/Menachos 89a, Pesachim 110b, and Nedarim 37b are all candidates, where each grouping of Gemaras is a distinct list of 2-3 halachos identified as הלכות למשה מסיני. There is no such Tosfos on the ones in Sukkah, but it could be on one of the others, or a different Rishon in Sukkah.

Comment: @DonielF I never claimed there's a gemarra that says the statement you wrote... I said a gemarra that groups halacha lemoshe misinai's together. In any event, you reminded me that 5b is a better example of what I meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @DonielF's comment, I recalled that I saw the motivation for this question in the context of `עשר נטיעות, ערבה, ונסוך המים` found in a few places, including **Moed Katan** 3b, **Sukkah** 34a, 44a, **Ta'anis** 3a, **Zevachim** 10b. Looking around in those areas I found what I was thinking of.

It's clear from [**Tosafos** to **Moed Kattan** 4a](https://www.sefaria.org/Tosafot_on_Moed_Katan.4a.9.1) that they understood that when grouped together this way it means they were taught together at Sinai:

> אלא אמר רב אשי רבן גמליאל כו'. ...וקא דייק רבן גמליאל מה שייכא תוספת שביעית גבי ניסוך **שניתנו למשה גבי הדדי דבכל מקום שונה הני שלשה ביחד דכך ניתנו** אלא ודאי למילף סמכינהו רחמנא:

However, [**Rashi** to **Sukkah** 34a](https://sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Sukkah.34a.2.2) disagrees. It's not that they're grouped together to show that they were originally said that way, it's that they are grouped together because that is how they were discussed in the *beis midrash*. The person who asked the source for these laws was told they're all *Halacha LeMoshe MiSinai*, and he grouped them together the way he learned.

> עשר נטיעות ערבה ונסוך המים הלכה למשה מסיני - אלו שלשה נשאלו בבית המדרש מנין להם מן התורה והשיבו שהלכה למשה מסיני הם ושמע השומע וגרסם כסדר ששמעם וכן שיעורים וחציצין ומחיצין (לעיל סוכה דף ה:) שמען השומע וסדרן כסדר ששמען וכן בכל מקום

**Rashi** says this is true throughout all of the *gemarra*, whenever you have a grouping of *halacha lemoshe misinai*'s.

I found that **Gilyonei HaShas**, by **Rav Yosef Engel**, to **Sukkah** 11b s.v. ענני הכבוד, seems to assume like Tosafos. He says that according to the **Mabit**, the Jews weren't in *sukkos* in the wilderness, as they had the Clouds of Glory. If so, the concept of דופן עקומה, which is a *Halacha LeMoshe MiSinai* which only applies to a *sukkah*, didn't apply. As such, he wants to say that the *Halacha LeMoshe MiSinai*s of גוד and לבוד also didn't apply in the wilderness, **since they were taught together**. Since this was before the *beis midrash* of *Chazal*, presumably he means taught together **at Sinai**.

Comment: Yay teamwork!!!